# How can I import the System.Linq namespace to Boo?

Tags: c#, namespaces, boo

When I try to import the `System.Linq` namespace to Boo compiler, I get this error:

> Boo.Lang.Compiler.CompilerError:
>
> Namespace 'System.Linq' not found, maybe you forgot to add an assembly reference?

I use "Rhino.DSL.dll" and my DSL engine code is here:

```
public class MyDslEngine : DslEngine
{
    protected override void CustomizeCompiler(BooCompiler compiler, CompilerPipeline pipeline, string[] urls)
    {
        pipeline.Insert(1, new AnonymousBaseClassCompilerStep(typeof(DslBase), "Prepare",
            "System.Linq",
            "Azarakhsh.Framework.Repository" //it's my repository framework
            ));
        pipeline.Insert(2, new UseSymbolsStep());
        pipeline.Insert(3, new RunScriptCompilerStep());
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you forgot to add an assembly reference? Most System.Linq classes are in the System.Core assembly.

Comment: SO what is the question? Vode to close. READ THE ERROR and add asembly reference as it says.

Comment: Hey TomTom READ THE CODE and then answer. thanks

Comment: thanks dtb, but my project has reference to System.Core

Comment: I guess you need to add make the reference visible to the Boo compiler, not just add it to the project that creates the Boo compiler.

Comment: i guess the same as you but i tried and it didnt work and the same error throwed.   Namespace 'System.Core' not found, ...

Comment: System.Core is an assembly, not a namespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you need System.Linq in your DSL? Sytem.Linq must be "hidden" in your framework. Besides using Linq in Boo, it's kinda of verbose (in my opinion) and your DSL should hide this verbose stuff...

```
import System.Linq.Enumerable from System.Core
bar = List of string() 
bar.Add("foo")
bar.Add("baz")

baz = bar.Where({x as string | x =="baz"}).Single()
```

About using the System.Linq, haven't tried but I found this link [Boo Markmail](http://markmail.org/message/bgf7j27bf6wryvve#query%3alinq%20boo+page:1+mid%3af7vtocfywtwqk5jd+state%3aresults), where the code above was copied...

Comment: thanks jjchiwi want use the 'System.Linq' functions such as 'FirstOrDefault()' in my dsl

Comment: and get this error: BCE0019: Boo.Lang.Compiler.CompilerError: 'FirstOrDefault' is not a member of 'System.Linq.IQueryable ...

Answer (score 4):

**Try adding a reference to the `System.Core` assembly to your project.** Most of the classes in the `System.Linq` namespace are found in that assembly.

If that doesn't work, you might also try adding a reference to `System.Data.Linq`.

And in the future, don't underestimate the usefulness of the error messages provided by the compiler. Yes, sometimes they are cryptic and other times they are even misleading. But they're certainly a good place to start when you're trying to figure out why something won't compile that you expected to work.

Comment: thanks from extra descriptions, but my project has reference to System.Core

Comment: @HLDN: I just updated my answer. Have you also included a reference to `System.Data.Linq`?

Comment: thanks i add "System.Data.Linq" and no error reported but i need to add "System.Linq" to use.